# Build cts query based on search grammar

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have a use-case where in I have to write custom REST extension and in it I have to build `cts:query` based on the user supplied text string. Is there a way I can utilize either

- pass the `cts:query` to `search:search` ?
- or how can I utilize the power of search grammar, the way `search:search` builds the `cts:query` ?

Custom search constraint will not work in my case.

------------ *Updated, giving more context*---------------

I have two different entity types in my database. When the user queries, I have get the results from both the entity types and them combine the results.. Each entity type have a different weighting scheme for its attributes.
so I ended up writing a custom REST extension where in I do build the `cts:query` for each entity type and then issue multiple `cts:search` and then combine results.. This works but fails when user sends with Search Grammar.
As as workaround (maybe it is not).. I have an API gateway and when user issues the call, In the API gateway I issue multiple calls using out-of-box search REST API, with search options for each entity-type and then in the GATEWAY, I combine them..
Now I have to maintain logic in marklogic and one in gateway.. which is fine.. I was looking to see if I can get away having everything in Marklogic

Comment: Looks like you are looking for `<additional-query>`. You have all the options for search:search in https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_67369

Answer (score 1):

Consider `cts:parse()`, which is the modern, faster, more flexible, and more robust alternative to search:parse() for generating a cts:query in not only XQuery but SJS:

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:parse

If you need to build a query structure on the client, one possibility is to build the serialization of cts:query using an XML or JSON DOM API on the client and to use the cts:query() constructor to parse the serialized cts:query on the enode.

You can see the XML serialization of a cts:query with:

```
xdmp:quote(document{...YOUR QUERY...}/*)
```

and the JSON serialization with:

```
xdmp:to-json-string(...YOUR QUERY...)
```

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Receiving and processing the qtext is fairly straight-forward: just use `search:parse`. It returns a cts:query, which can be merged with other cts queries, and passed into either `search:resolve`, an optic query (where you feed the cts query as argument into `op:where`), or into `cts:search` the old-fashioned way.

Processing a structured-query is more difficult. There are no official apis exposed to convert that to cts query, unfortunately..

HTH!